# How do I append data to existing row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, append

I'm trying to append data to an existing row in a SQL Server table. But I'm getting a syntax error near the where clause.

Here's my query:

```
update OINV
set U_CollectionNotes = Cast('Cancelled 07.01.14., as nvarchar(max))' + U_CollectionNotes
where oinv.DocNum = 47651
```

Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the incorrect Cast statement, see correction below:

```
update OINV 
set U_CollectionNotes = Cast('Cancelled 07.01.14' as nvarchar(max)) + U_CollectionNotes 
where oinv.DocNum = 47651
```

Comment: Thanks Kokkie but now I'm getting the following: The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the add operator. and when I change nvarchar to ntext, I get Operand data type ntext is invalid for add operator.

Comment: ok, so the field is of the type ntext in stead of nvarchar. You should replace nvarchar(max) with ntext.

Comment: when I change nvarchar to ntext, I get Operand data type ntext is invalid for add operator.

Comment: @user3801599: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Change the type of the colomn and then it should work; ALTER TABLE OINV
ALTER COLUMN U_CollectionNotes nvarchar(max)